# HTTPS Mixed Content prompt when HTTPS page hosts HTTP subframe

Tags: iframe, ssl

I'm using an iframe technology that places my html page inside of a 'landing page' hosted by our clients.

The problem in 1 situation is the page hosted by the client is HTTPS and it shows the Security Warning: Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered security? Yes No

I want this to be resolved... not sure what to do. We have an SSL certificate which works but that particular iframe page, when accessing via https on my local box, it shows the SSL Warning that its not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content.aspx) for some background about mixed content. In general, you can't have a HTTP-based subframe of a HTTPS-based page; if you do, you'll encounter this warning in most browsers in some form or another (some show a notification bar, a broken lock, or other indicator).

You'll either need to change the page so that the top-level isn't HTTPS, or so that the subpage is also HTTPS and bears a valid certificate.

Comment: I don't have access to the client side and we need to make changes on our end.

The iframe looks like src="http://xdomain.com/XXX/thepage.aspx?etcetcetc

You're suggesting to make the XXX page https enabled in IIS? any guidance?